# Filter in Azure Data Factory

Tags: sql, join, azure-data-factory

I have 2 sources as follows:

[image]

I need to do a filter on Source 1 such that output contains only values with Colors except Green, Blue, Black:

[image]

This is how my data flow looks like:

[image]

Is there a different way to do this using a join with Source 2 Color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to filter the person names based on color names, then you'll need to first join and then you can filter on color name.

Comment: What join should be used: left outer, right outer, inner, full outer?

Comment: Use a Lookup transformation, that would be a better fit for this use case. Lookup is equivalent to a Left Outer. Left-hand side should be Source 1.